# How to retrieve username and password after getting from database to a vriable in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, database, laravel

UserLoginController.php

This is login controller to redirect to homepage after verifying username and password.

```
 public function userLogin(UserLoginRequest $request){
            //  return view('welcome');
        // echo "Login Page";
         $input = Input::all();
         $data = User::get(['name','password'])->where('name',$input['name'])
         ->where('password',$input['password']);
         $datas = collect($data);
         //What should I do here for matching username and password and redirect to  another page.
         dd($datas);
    }
```

Output:This is the output after dumping variabl `$datas`

```
Collection {#157 ▼
      #items: array:1 [▼
        0 => User {#187 ▼
          #fillable: array:3 [▶]
          #hidden: array:2 [▶]
          #connection: null
          #table: null
          #primaryKey: "id"
          #keyType: "int"
          #perPage: 15
          +incrementing: true
          +timestamps: true
          #attributes: array:2 [▼
            "name" => "girdhari013"
            "password" => "girdhari@"
          ]
          #original: array:2 [▼
            "name" => "girdhari013"
            "password" => "girdhari@"
          ]
          #relations: []
          #visible: []
          #appends: []
          #guarded: array:1 [▶]
          #dates: []
          #dateFormat: null
          #casts: []
          #touches: []
          #observables: []
          #with: []
          #morphClass: null
          +exists: true
          +wasRecentlyCreated: false
        }
      ]
    }
```

routes.php

// This is to redirect after clicking on submit button.

```
 Route::any('/login-verify',[
           'uses' => 'UserLoginController@userLogin',
           'as' => 'login.form'
         ]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$data = User::get(['name','password'])->where('name',$input['name'])
         ->where('password',$input['password']);
```

must be:

```
$data = User::where('name', '=', $request->input('name'))
            ->where('password', '=', \Hash::make($request->input('password')))->first();
```

for get username or password, just do:

```
$data->name
$data->password
```

Comment: I think. It will work but when I'm using if statement below above line then it is showing syntax error, unexpected 'if'  @Cristian

Comment: Edit post, try again. Are you sure the field name exists?

Comment: Above code is working but after that I'm writing this code :
`@if(matching data) //Giving error
         protected $redirectTo = '/home'; 
  @endif
  @else  Redirect::back()->with('message','Username or password not Match!'); `

Comment: Re-edited post for password hash. You no need to use `@` in php, just use simple `if` and brackets

Comment: `if(count($data) == 1){
   return view('welcome');
  }
  else {
   Redirect::back()->with('message','Username or password not Match!'); 
  }`
else part is not working. @Cristian Consenza

Comment: add `return` before `Redirect::back()` @giridhari-lal

Answer (score 0):

You have to make proper hash using `Hash` facade:

```
$data = User::get(['name','password'])->where('name',\Request::get('name'))
         ->where('password',\Hash::make(\Request::get('password')));
```